# Parallel calling of an external program in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

As in topic I have a problem with parallel calling of external program in C++. I prepared code showed below that uses system() to call my program but it is not thread safe and results are random - some runs are fine other return errors. Is there any other possible method to run it parallel in thread safe mode? For now I use bat file with multiple start commands and wait when all threads return output files, but it is very ugly solution.

```
vector<thread> threadArray;

    int nThread= 0;

    // run calcs

    for (int nThread = 0; nThread < quantity; nThread++)
    {
        threadArray.push_back(thread(system, ("start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_" + to_string(nThread)).c_str()));
        threadArray.push_back(thread(system, ("start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_" + to_string(nThread)).c_str()));
        cout << ("start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_" + to_string(nThread)).c_str() << endl;
        cout << ("start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_" + to_string(nThread)).c_str() << endl;
    }

    for (auto it = threadArray.begin(); it != threadArray.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->join();
    }
```

I have found some simmilar topics but none of them was helpful.

The program is a structrural stress solver Calculix. Here is cmd output:

```
start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_0
start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_0
start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_1
start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_1
start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_2
start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_2
start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_3
start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_3
start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_4
start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_4
start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_5
start ccx.exe Calculix_fus_5
'üÜ+' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Čŕ+' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'l' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'o' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'îţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţî
ţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţî
ţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţîţ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'l' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

There must be a problem with thread safety as you can see in output. At the beginning there lines with start command - not exetutable, and then the errors related with system() in parallel run. In this particular run only two calculations finished with succeed, with '2' at the end. Hovewer this is random, sometimes 5 runs is done, sometimes 3. When I create from first lines a bat file everything is ok. I expect to run ccx.exe for every input and then wait till all threads finish calculations to further postprocessing output files.

Comment: What errors do you get? What is the program that you "call" doing that make it not thread-safe? The code you show here do nothing that could be unsafe.

Comment: You're going to need to give more details.  What kind of errors? What behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: For [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) it says "The function accesses the array pointed by command.
Concurrently calling this function with a null pointer as argument is safe. Otherwise, it depends on the system and library implementation." Might be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `("start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_" + to_string(nThread))` creates a *temporary* `std::string` object, and since you then use `c_str` to get a pointer, the [thread constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) only *copies* the pointer to this temporary object. Once the constructor returns, the temporary object is destructed and the thread is left with a dangling pointer.

Using dangling (or otherwise illegal) pointers leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is what you're seeing.

There is really no way of solving this directly, you have to use a wrapper function that takes a `std::string` object as argument, and let the thread constructor copy the temporary string object instead. For this you can use a lambda:

```
threadArray.push_back(thread(
    [](const std::string arg) { system(arg.c_str()); },
    ("start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_" + to_string(nThread))));
```

Or not pass an argument at all:

```
threadArray.push_back(thread(
    [nThread]()
    {
        system(("start ccx.exe Calculix_wings_" + to_string(nThread)));
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used second code with additional c_str(). Now it works fine.